# laravel 4.2 laravel-dompdf can't pass variables to template

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have the following :

```
 PDF::loadView('emails.pagoHechoPDF', compact('order', 'address', 'user'))
        ->setPaper('a4')
        ->setOrientation('landscape')
        ->save('temp/comprobantedepago'. $pago->order_id .'.pdf');
```

But when I download the PDF prints " {{$order->required_date}} " instead of the value.

I tried too

```
PDF::loadView('emails.pagoHechoPDF', array('order'=>$order, 'address'=>$address, 'user'=>$user))
        ->setPaper('a4')
        ->setOrientation('landscape')
        ->save('temp/comprobantedepago'. $pago->order_id .'.pdf');
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the full name and path of the file `emails.pagoHechoPDF` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte what a dumb, I forgot to add ".blade" in the file name. Thank you so much anyway! Is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the `blade` string in the file name:

```
resources/views/emails/pagoHechoPDF.blade.php
```